# Pass SwitchParameter as a argument

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm wondering how can I do to pass SwitchParameter as an argument.

```
function ExecuteWindowsTaskScheduler {
    param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $TaskName #e.g. "Open Notepad task"
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $TimeToExecute #e.g. "3:45pm/am"
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter] $FrequencyToExecute #e.g. -Once, -Daily, -Weekly, -DaysInterval...
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $DomainAndUser #e.g. "yourdomain\yourusername"
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $ProgramWithPath #e.g. "C:\PowerShell\yourFile.ps1"
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [bool]  ${DebugMode}
        )



    $Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $TimeToExecute -Once # Specify the trigger settings
    $Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument $ProgramWithPath # Specify what script to run and with its parameters
    $TaskExists= Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $TaskName }

    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Trigger $Trigger -User $DomainAndUser -Action $Action

}

ExecuteWindowsTaskScheduler "Open Notepad task" "11:56am" -Once "xxx\yyy" "C:\PowerShell\OpenNotepad.ps1"
```

I have the parameter `$FrequencyToExecute` and, when I call the function, I'd like to be able to pass one of these commands: <kbd>-Once</kbd>, <kbd>-Daily</kbd>, <kbd>-Weekly</kbd>, etc.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: If I understand, you may be asking about parameter sets. Run `help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` (see the section regarding parameter sets).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to change the parameter type to `[string]` and then use a `[ValidateSet]` attribute to enforce a value of either "Once", "Daily" or "Weekly", and then use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to pass the appropriate switch to `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`:

```
function ExecuteWindowsTaskScheduler {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$TaskName, #e.g. "Open Notepad task"

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$TimeToExecute, #e.g. "3:45pm/am"

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet('Once','Daily','Weekly','Monthly')]
        [string]$FrequencyToExecute, #e.g. -Once, -Daily, -Weekly, Monthly

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$DomainAndUser, #e.g. "yourdomain\yourusername"

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ProgramWithPath, #e.g. "C:\PowerShell\yourFile.ps1"

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [bool]${DebugMode}
    )

    $TriggerParams = @{
        At = $TimeToExecute
    }
    # Add the appropriate frequency value to the splatting table
    if ($FrequencyToExecute -eq 'Monthly') {
        $TriggerParams.Add('Weekly',$true)
        $TriggerParams.Add('WeeksInterval',4)
        $TriggerParams.Add('DaysOfWeek','Monday')
    }
    elseif ($FrequencyToExecute -eq 'Weekly') {
        $TriggerParams.Add('Weekly',$true)
        $TriggerParams.Add('WeeksInterval',1)
        $TriggerParams.Add('DaysOfWeek','Monday')
    }
    else {
        $TriggerParams.Add($FrequencyToExecute,$true)
    }

    $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger @TriggerParams

    $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument $ProgramWithPath # Specify what script to run and with its parameters
    $TaskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $TaskName }

    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Trigger $Trigger -User $DomainAndUser -Action $Action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [parameter sets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/)

You'll define all of your desired parameters, but each will be in a differently-named ParameterSet. This makes them mutually-exclusive when parameter binding takes place.